# Error mounting swap after mobo and CPU upgrade

Tags: boot, mount, swap

I went from a Xeon E5450 to a E5-2680v2 a few days ago.
Aside from killing my network setup, I am now having a few issues during boot I would like to address.

I will split this into several post for the sake of keeping everything ordered.

Now this post is about two disk issues I'm having: 1: journalctl -b has the following messages:

```
>Nov 15 21:39:59 nucleus kernel: scsi 7:0:9:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0 
>Nov 15 21:39:59 nucleus kernel: scsi 7:0:9:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0 
>Nov 15 21:39:59 nucleus kernel: scsi 7:0:9:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0 
>Nov 15 21:39:59 nucleus kernel: scsi 7:0:9:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0 
>Nov 15 21:39:59 nucleus kernel: scsi 7:0:9:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0 
>Nov 15 21:39:59 nucleus kernel: scsi 7:0:9:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0 
>Nov 15 21:39:59 nucleus kernel: scsi 7:0:9:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0 
>Nov 15 21:39:59 nucleus kernel: random: crng init done 
>Nov 15 21:39:59 nucleus kernel: scsi 7:0:9:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0 
>Nov 15 21:39:59 nucleus kernel: scsi 7:0:9:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0 
>Nov 15 21:39:59 nucleus kernel: scsi 7:0:9:0: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 7 got 0 
>Nov 15 21:39:59 nucleus kernel: ses 7:0:9:0: Attached Enclosure device 
>Nov 15 21:39:59 nucleus kernel: raid6: sse2x1 gen() 8785 MB/s 
>Nov 15 21:39:59 nucleus kernel: raid6: sse2x1 xor() 7083 MB/s Nov 15 21:39:59 nucleus kernel: raid6: sse2x2 gen() 11168 MB/s 
>Nov 15 21:39:59 nucleus kernel: raid6: sse2x2 xor() 7630 MB/s
```

The interesting thing is that after the line
ses 7:0:9:0: Attached Enclosure device
despite the timestamps saying otherwise, it takes half a minute or more for the next steps to appear on screen.

I do not know whether this has any impact but I found it worth mentioning

2:

```
Nov 15 21:41:28 nucleus systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-99357771\x2d97a4\x2d476b\x2da82e\x2d2bfb8d4dd759.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-99357771\x2d97a4\x2d476b\x2da82e\x2d2bfb8d4dd759.device/start timed out. 
Nov 15 21:41:28 nucleus systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-99357771\x2d97a4\x2d476b\x2da82e\x2d2bfb8d4dd759.device. 
Nov 15 21:41:28 nucleus systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/99357771-97a4-476b-a82e-2bfb8d4dd759. Nov 15 21:41:28 nucleus systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Swap. Nov 15 21:41:28 nucleus systemd[1]: swap.target: Job swap.target/start failed with result 'dependency'. 
Nov 15 21:41:28 nucleus systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-99357771\x2d97a4\x2d476b\x2da82e\x2d2bfb8d4dd759.swap: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-99357771\x2d97a4\x2d476b\x2da82e\x2d2bfb8d4dd759.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'. 
Nov 15 21:41:28 nucleus systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-99357771\x2d97a4\x2d476b\x2da82e\x2d2bfb8d4dd759.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-99357771\x2d97a4\x2d476b\x2da82e\x2d2bfb8d4dd759.devi
```

For some reason, the swap partition will not be mounted. As far as I can tell the UUID is correct although the disk went from /dev/sda to /dev/sdb on the new hardware. I am planning to correct this, however with UUIDs I thought this should not be an issue especially considering that this is now /dev/sdb5 we're talking about and root is on /dev/sdb1 and that seems to be working fine.

Manually running swapon -a will mount the swap without issues.

Please let me know which log entries I can provide for someone to make sense of this.

Edit: smartctl only shows one CRC error and nothing else. I think the hardware should be fine still.

I have found a post via google that mentioned the same issue that was solved by either removing the swap from fstab or not formatting it as Linux swap. It seems having both will also try mounting it twice. I have commented the line in fstab and will see about the results.

Also thank you for formatting this post.

Comment: the only thing that comes to mind scanning your post is have you looked at the health of your SSD?   ie. using 'smartctl' or whatever tool you fancy to check the health of your hardware?  (for swap I'd just erase & remake the partition .. but checking the hardware would be my first step)